# how to bind data in reactjs form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have started working on reactjs technology and i am totally new for this technology. I wanted to bind data with my drop down in form and on drop down item selection i wanted to feed my other form fields.Here i am creating form to generate bill for society members and i wanted to fill society member name to be bind on drop down box and bill changes on text fields. Sometimes i have got issue says 'TypeError: node is null".And i dont understand how to bind the data to fields.

here is my logic please check and let me know what am i missing over here

```
 constructor(props, fdb) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            bill_nm: '',
            bill_eml: '',
            bill_total: '',
            bill_id: '',
            inputs:[],
            userInput:[]
        };
        this.userState = {
            user_id:'',
            email:'',
            first_name:'',
            last_name:''
        };
        this.chargeState ={
            charge_id:'',
            charge_title:'',
            charge_type:'',
            charge_amt:''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmitFirebase = this.handleSubmitFirebase.bind(this);
        this.sendCallback = this.sendCallback.bind(this);
        this.appendInput = this.appendInput.bind(this);
        this.getInitialState = this.getInitialState.bind(this);
        this.appendUserInput = this.appendUserInput.bind(this);
        this.usercharge = [];

        const rootRef = DbConfig.database().ref();
        const post = rootRef.child('billing').orderByKey();
        const users = rootRef.child('users').orderByKey();
        const bill_charges = rootRef.child('billing_charges').orderByKey();

    }

    componentDidMount() {

             this.users.once('value', snap => {
            snap.forEach(child => {
                this.userState = {
                    user_id: child.key,
                    email: child.val().email,
                    first_name: child.val().first_name,
                    last_name: child.val().last_name
                };

            });

        });

        this.bill_charges.once('value', snap => {
            snap.forEach(child => {
                this.chargeState = {
                    chrage_key:child.key,
                    charge_id: child.charge_id,
                    charge_title: child.val().charge_title,
                    charge_type: child.val().charge_type,
                    charge_amt: child.val().charge_amt
                };
                this.usercharge = this.chargeState;
               //console.log( this.usercharge);
            });
        });

        }

           handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    }


   getInitialState() {
        return {inputs:[]};
    }
    appendUserInput() {
        //e.preventDefault();

        // DbConfig.database().ref().child('users').orderByKey().once('value', snap => {
        //     snap.forEach(child => {
        //         this.userState = {
        //             user_id: child.key,
        //             email: child.val().email,
        //             first_name: child.val().first_name,
        //             last_name: child.val().last_name
        //         };
        //     });
        // });
        var newInput1 = this.state.userInput.length;
       // var newInput = this.userState.length;
        console.log('len1='+newInput1);
       // console.log('len'+newInput);
        this.setState({ userInput: this.state.userInput.concat(newInput1)});

    }
    appendInput(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newInput = this.state.inputs.length;
            console.log('newinput'+newInput);
        this.setState({ inputs: this.state.inputs.concat(newInput)},function(){
            return;
        });
        console.log('input concate'+this.state.inputs);
    }

      render() {
        return (
            <div className="content">
                <NavBar></NavBar>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="rose">
                                <i className="material-icons">receipt</i>
                            </div>
                            <div className="card-content">
                                <h4 className="card-title">Add Bill</h4>
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitFirebase}>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                        <label className="control-label">Person Name</label>

                                        <div className="room-main">
                                        <div className="online-est">                                         
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.appendUserInput} className="rednew-btn"><i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add user</a>
                                            <select className="room-form">
                                           {this.state.userInput.map(function(item){
                                               console.log('i'+item);
                                                return (
                                                          <option ref={item}>{item}</option> 
                                                       )
                                           })}
                                           </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                    <label className="control-label">Person Name</label>
                                        <div className="room-main">
                                        <div className="online-est"> 
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.appendInput} className="rednew-btn"><i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add charge</a>
                                            <select>
                                           {this.state.inputs.map(function(item){
                                                return (
                                                            <option ref={item}>{item}</option>
                                                       )
                                           })}
                                           </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                            <label className="control-label">status</label>
                                            <select>
                                                <option value="Unpaid">Unpaid</option>
                                                <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
                                            </select>
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                            <label className="control-label">total</label>
                                            <input type="text" className="form-control" ref={el => this.billtotal = el} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                            <label className="control-label">Bill period</label>
                                            <input type="date" className="form-control" ref={el => this.billto = el} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                            <input type="date" className="form-control" ref={el => this.billfrom = el} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <div className="form-group label-floating is-empty">
                                        <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-fill btn-rose">Submit</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: When does the error message show up? Is it during render? Or does the form render properly, but error message comes when you do something in the form? If it is when you do something in the form, then please include the onChange function code as well

Comment: error message is 'TypeError: node is null' and it display during rendering.

Comment: form is not being render this error comes at the time of page load it prevent displaying another component on page it gives me blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using get initial state you can use a constructor, initialise state in your constructor and bind your methods in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    listVisible: false
  };
 this.select = this.select.bind(this)
 this.show = this.show.bind(this)
 this.hide = this.hide.bind(this)
 this.renderListItems = this.renderListItems.bind(this)
}
```

Then when you call select in your render method you should just be able to say...

```
<div onClick={this.select(item)}>
  <span>{item.name}</span>
</div>
```

although you need to add a key in react to keep track fo lists so change the first line to `<div key={i} onClick={this.select(item)}>`. You can read up on keys seperately https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: You can also do this without a constructor and bind this using arrow functions but that uses ES7. I think understanding and using this approach is the best, for now, it is the way the Airbnb style guide recommends and that is the closest thing we have to an industry standard.

Comment: i have did the same but it says "this.props.selected.name" , this.props.list is undefied

Comment: You're going to have to give me more than that. Where does is say this? what triggers the error?

Comment: Use react developer tools or console.log to check that your list is being passed in as you expect if it is saying that list is undefined.

Comment: this error also met me when page load and this dispaly in my console winsdow only

Comment: So I added item as a parameter into the select method call in my example. Make sure you didn't make that mistake. For me to help you debug this you need to try and console log ```this.props.list``` in your ```renderListItems()``` method and see if it is being passed in correctly. If it is taking a little while to get the data then try replacing your call to the function with ```{this.props.list && this.renderListItems()}``` when you call the function in your render method.

Comment: if my response solved your problem please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div className="post">
  <h3>{this.state.bill_nm}</h3>
  <h2>{this.state.bill_eml}</h2>
  <p>{this.state.bill_total}</p>
</div>
```

These state values above have never been defined. You need to define them in your initial state, or set them before they can be called.

In your onChange handlers on the inputs in render, you are calling `this.handleChange` but they havn't been defined either.

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" ref={el => this.pnm = el} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

I think this code example is incomplete.

To answer the title question, this article explains your options for binding `this` in react https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could try Redux Form https://redux-form.com which will do a good part of the work for you

Comment: Jumping to redux as a solution for not understanding the fundamental of state and binding this in react is a terrible idea.